# Textures blur far from camera Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, blur, texture-mapping

I have a threejs scene, with my camera like this:

```
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH  / SCREEN_HEIGHT , NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 8000;

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
```

and i create the material like this:

```
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'Images/floor62.jpg' );
floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
floorTexture.repeat.set( 3, 105 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
                    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(250, 10500 );
```

and then I create the road you see in the pic. it goes far in z-axis and it is made of rectangles dressed with good-quality textures.

The problem is it blurs very close to the camera (as you can see in the pic). This is not normal and it gives a taste of cheap unreal graphics in the scene.

How can I fix this?

thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need `side: THREE.DoubleSide`. I assume you don't go under the road.

Comment: that is true but still the problem remains.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to issues with [anisotropic filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering), have two options: modify the algorithm entirely or (most likely) turn up the sampling rate.

Modify [Texture.minFilter](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.minFilter) to change how a texture is sampled when a texel covers less than one pixel. Modify [Texture.magFilter](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.magFilter) to do the opposite: change how the texture is sampled when a texel covers more than one pixel.

To turn up the sampling rate, modify [Texture.anisotropy](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.anisotropy).

In both cases, if you are modifying the texture after you initially load your scene, remember to set `Texture.needsUpdate = true;` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use `floorTexture.generateMipmaps = false;`. The default setting is `true` in which case the renderer uses lower resolution textures for polygons far from the camera. `Mipmaps` are generally a good thing. Less memory on the graphics card.

Comment: I used this line and it made my mesh dissapear! I don't know why.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are in a situation where the resolution of the texture is lower than needed.

In this case, you have 2 posibilities. From the three.js doc:

> .magFilter
>
> How the texture is sampled when a texel covers more than one pixel.
>   The default is THREE.LinearFilter, which takes the four closest texels
>   and bilinearly interpolates among them. The other option is
>   THREE.NearestFilter, which uses the value of the closest texel.

So, you can try to set magFilter to Nearest, where the `pixelation of the texture is kept

Comment: the textures are good quality. I tried to do what you said with magFilter nothing got better.

Answer (score 0):

you can set this `Texture.anisotropy` is a number, detail you'can see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/zh/textures/Texture.anisotropy, I'm from chinese, hope help u ^_^